# Conditional Increment on Python DataFrame Column Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a date frame with 3 columns as given below :

```
FirstEpisode       ShowOnAir       AfterPremier
     0                  0             0
     0                  0             0
     1                  1             1
     0                  1             2 
     0                  1             3
     0                  0             0
     1                  1             1
     0                  1             2
```

The condition here is that , When the First Episode ==1 & ShowOnAir ==1 , then AfterPremier should become 1 , and , if the value of ShowOnAir in the next observation is still 1 , then the value of AfterPremier should be increment by 1 , till the value of ShowOnAir is not 0 again ,

Would really appreciate if I could get help for the same

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [`df.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
df['AfterPremier'] = 0

df_to_iter = df.copy()
for i, row in df_to_iter.iterrows():
    if row['FirstEpisode'] == 1 and row['ShowOnAir'] == 1:
        row['AfterPremier'] = 1
    if row['ShowOnAir'] == 1 and row['FirstEpisode'] == 0 and df.loc[i-1, 'AfterPremier'] != 0:
        row['AfterPremier'] = df.loc[i-1, 'AfterPremier'] + 1

In [121]: df
Out[121]:
   FirstEpisode  ShowOnAir  AfterPremier
0             0          0             0
1             0          0             0
2             1          1             1
3             0          1             2
4             0          1             3
5             0          0             0
6             1          1             1
7             0          1             2
```

Comment: "You should never modify something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases." see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html